# Laravel 5.5 fail when serve

Tags: php, laravel-5

5 project and after install Laravel and make `php artisan serve` it fails.

> PHP Warning: require(/var/www/html/sidbrint/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/sidbrint/artisan on line 18
>
> PHP Fatal error: require():
>   Failed opening required '/var/www/html/sidbrint/vendor/autoload.php
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/sidbrint/artisan on
>   line 18

I'm using an Ubuntu Server and I don't know hat to do.

---

When I install Laravel I use `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"`

If I don't put the version, it installs the 5.4 version, that works fine, but I need version 5.5 because is LTS.

Comment: When I have to run `composer install`?

Comment: You don't! Removed my comment after you made changes to your post on how you installed it.

Comment: Everything should (theoretically) work after what you did. You could try to install into a different folder to see if that works. You could run `composer dump-autoload` in your project folder, see if that helps.

Comment: You can also refer to https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/

Comment: The second error message may indicate you still have to install php.  On ubuntu if 'ls /usr/share/php/' shows no subdirectories then you need to install php.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this it might solve your issue

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

composer update

is required as the vendor files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I needed some PHP packages, so I installed them:

```
sudo apt-get install php-dev php-mcrypt php-gd php-mbstring php-xml php-common php-zip apache2-dev libapache2-mod-php mysql-server composer npm
```

After this I executed `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.5.*"` and worked fine.

I have consulted this:

[How to Install Laravel 5.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache](https://www.techrrival.com/install-laravel-ubuntu-apache/)